# Change LaunchScreen during runtime

Tags: flutter

I would like to be able to change the launch screen of the app based on the chosen theme (the in-app setting).

For example:
White screen for light theme
Black screen for dark theme

Is it possible to choose the launch screen during runtime, after checking which theme is used ?

I have found this package: [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)

But as the author points out in FAQ section it does not allow to control the splash screen from Flutter, as it is loaded before Flutter is loaded.

I would like to be able, for instance force Xcode to use a one of the two launch screens, before the app is loaded. How would I go about it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: By "chosen theme" did you mean the device's dark/light mode setting, or the in-app theme setting? You could provide that information in the question.

Comment: Why don't you create your own splash screen? Just create 2 screens and write conditions (if..else or ternary operator) to choose which screen should be launched

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I mean in-app

Comment: @BosS How would I go about writing such a condition ? Not sure where should it be handled, as I kind of want to determine it before the app is loaded

Comment: I recommend to learn how to change theme mode, if you mean only screen background and text color should be changed so toggling theme mode to dark or vice versa is enough.